# Need to merge two pandas dataframe using two columns latitude and longitude

Tags: python, pandas, merge, latitude-longitude

this is my dataframe#1 :city names with its latitude and longitude

```
df1 = {"city":['delhi','new york','london','paris','chennai'],"lat":[12.23,22.444,23.233,45.32,34.22],"long":[11.22,22.332,34.23,55.23,24.22]
```

this is dataframe#2 : country names with latitude and longitude

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"country":['India','US','UK','France','India'],"lat":[12.13,22.54,22.33,45.32,34.22],"long":[11.12,22.132,34.23,54.23,24.22]})
```

I need to match these two columns lat and long to merge these two tables. the problem is the lat and long is not exactly matching and the values are + or - 0.1 or 0.2. (if matched I can use the pd.merge option)
**lat and longs are not real here. just an example**

Expected Result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({"city":['delhi','new york','london','paris','chennai'],"country":['India','US','UK','France','India'],"lat":[12.13,22.54,22.33,45.32,34.22],"long":[11.12,22.132,34.23,54.23,24.22]})
```

what is the best approach to merge these tables?

Comment: is it will be enough to use integer part of the values?

Comment: no... If we matched the integer part only we missed the correct match of city and its country in real data.

Comment: cross merge and query if your data are not too big.

Comment: @QuangHoang: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example of a cross merge:

```
(df1.assign(dummy=1)
    .merge(df2.assign(dummy=1),on='dummy')
    .query('abs(lat_x-lat_y)<=0.1 and abs(long_x-long_y)<=0.2')
    .drop('dummy', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
        city   lat_x  long_x country  lat_y  long_y
0      delhi  12.230  11.220   India  12.13  11.120
6   new york  22.444  22.332      US  22.54  22.132
24   chennai  34.220  24.220   India  34.22  24.220
```

Comment: It works good. By adjust the limitations to 0.25, I can get good results. thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Geopandas](https://geopandas.org) may be use here.

Provided that you have boundaries of countries as polygons, you can use [spacial joins](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html?highlight=merge#spatial-joins).

In your question, you are reducing countries to single points which may not be the best representation.

Example from the documentation:

In a Spatial Join, two geometry objects are merged based on their spatial relationship to one another.

```
# One GeoDataFrame of countries, one of Cities.
# Want to merge so we can get each city's country.
In [11]: countries.head()
Out[11]: 


                                           geometry                   country
0  MULTIPOLYGON (((180.000000000 -16.067132664, 1...                      Fiji
1  POLYGON ((33.903711197 -0.950000000, 34.072620...                  Tanzania
2  POLYGON ((-8.665589565 27.656425890, -8.665124...                 W. Sahara
3  MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.840000000 49.000000000, -...                    Canada
4  MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.840000000 49.000000000, -...  United States of America

In [12]: cities.head()
Out[12]: 
           name                           geometry
0  Vatican City  POINT (12.453386545 41.903282180)
1    San Marino  POINT (12.441770158 43.936095835)
2         Vaduz   POINT (9.516669473 47.133723774)
3    Luxembourg   POINT (6.130002806 49.611660379)
4       Palikir  POINT (158.149974324 6.916643696)

# Execute spatial join
In [13]: cities_with_country = geopandas.sjoin(cities, countries, how="inner", op='intersects')

In [14]: cities_with_country.head()
Out[14]: 
             name                           geometry  index_right  country
0    Vatican City  POINT (12.453386545 41.903282180)          141    Italy
1      San Marino  POINT (12.441770158 43.936095835)          141    Italy
192          Rome  POINT (12.481312563 41.897901485)          141    Italy
2           Vaduz   POINT (9.516669473 47.133723774)          114  Austria
184        Vienna  POINT (16.364693097 48.201961137)          114  Austria
```

If you don't have the polygons representing the countries, you need to extend the point representing each country to an area. You can do this using the [buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer) method in [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) that is extending a point to an area given a distance:

```
Point(0, 0).buffer(10.0),
```

assuming a point at coordinates `[0,0]` and a distance of `10.0`.

Comment: No. It works on geometries. Whether the point is contained in the polygon for instance.

Comment: in the given example one geometry is polygon and another one is point.. In my case both are points. does it affect the process?

Comment: You can do this by extending points to areas using the `buffer` method. I edited the answer.